# Unable to test Kubuntu on live USB?

Tags: boot, usb, kubuntu, live-usb

I downloaded Kubuntu 18.04.3, verified the checksum, and installed it on my USB via MultiBootUSB. When I tried booting into Kubuntu, I noticed there wasn't a "Test without installing" option like with other Ubuntu flavors, it just said "Start Kubuntu". After starting Kubuntu it had the installation popup window and said something about starting the installation. I panicked and just shut down the laptop, thankfully it didn't corrupt my current Ubuntu installation.

Is there supposed to be a "Test without installing" option? If so, why isn't it showing up for me? If not, is there any other way to test Kubuntu on a live key?

Comment: I'd suggest always using the "check disc for defects" option to verify the write-to-media (be it dvd/thumb-drive/other).  You verified the download; that additional step will verify the 'write-to-media' was perfect...  (ie. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck  *where CD means dvd, thumb-drive or any install media too*)

Comment: Clarification: Kubuntu ISO image by default has "Start Kubuntu" as the only visible menu option to allow user to choose either "Try Kubuntu" or "Install Kubuntu" _after_ booting into a minimal live environment, which will show only a graphical window with those two options. If that is not what user see, then live USB was prepared improperly by the tool or affected by other factors in the process.